# List of Radio Button state pressed in Android?

Tags: android, radio-button, android-sqlite

I have radio button list in alert dialog where I have to select option like alarm after 10 mints, 15 mints and n mints, But when I click on one radio button and again opening a laert dialog radio button remain un-clicked but I want selected option to be clicked. how's it is possible? Is there any need to store it's state in database or any other solution?

My Activity:

```
 case RADIOBTN_DIALOG_ID:    
        AlertDialog.Builder builder2=new AlertDialog.Builder(Task_Details.this)
        .setTitle("Select Reminder Time")
        .setSingleChoiceItems(reminder_radio, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            switch(which)
            {
            case 0:
                AlarmReceiver alarm = new AlarmReceiver();
                alarm.CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                alarm.OneMintAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                AlarmReceiver alarm1 = new AlarmReceiver();
                alarm1.CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                alarm1.TenMintAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                AlarmReceiver alarm2 = new AlarmReceiver();
                alarm2.CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                alarm2.FifteenMintAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                AlarmReceiver alarm3 = new AlarmReceiver();
                alarm3.CancelAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                alarm3.nMintAlarm(getApplicationContext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

BroadCastReceiver Activity:

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, " Alarm Received !!! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}
public void OneMintAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 10, recurringDownload);
}
public void TenMintAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 600, recurringDownload);
}
public void FifteenMintAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent recurringDownload = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
            1000 * 900, recurringDownload);
}

public void nMintAlarm(Context context)
{
    }
```

Please suggest what to do??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> but I want selected option to be clicked. how's it is possible? Is
>   there any need to store it's state in database or any other solution?

Yes you need to store the state of the radio button, best choice here to [PreferenceManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html)

Comment: using database? are already using database in your application? why don't you want to use PreferenceManager? is there any concern?

Comment: I am using database, Is it possible to use preferences on alert Dialog ? or it is mandatory to use menu options to use preferences? I have used in my previous project but there i have used sync option in menu options.

Comment: no it's not mandatory all you need is to store your radio buttons stats in the preferences manager check preet answer [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11027631/488434)